# How does Docker name repositories?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

In a directory called `ringer` i've created a simple Dockerfile that will install some stuff and mount my app... I have never explicitly set a name.

I then used a `docker-compose.yml` file to define `web` and pointed it at the `Dockerfile` i mentioned above.

When i run `docker images` i see the following:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ringer_web                     latest              bf9b931e1030        8 minutes ago       938.9 MB
```

It looks like Docker named my image's repository after the local directory and image name... My question is, how exactly does Docker choose to name an image's repository? (and if applicable, why)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name):

> COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
>
> Sets the project name, which is prepended to the name of every container started by Compose. Defaults to the basename of the current working directory.

BTW, this is not `docker`, but `docker-compose` that is deciding on the name. To change it, set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` before running `docker-compose`:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myprefix docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that this naming comes from `docker-compose`! Appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to make it persistent, create a file `.env` in the same folder and set it there: `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myprefix` per https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/